# Binding List to Datatable After Page Loads (Not Lazy Loading)

Tags: java, icefaces

Our page has a datatable which shows records from a web service. The web service queries a database, and the query can take from 10 secs to 100 secs.

I was initially loading the arraylist binded to the datatable in the backing  bean constructor:

```
private ArrayList myList;
public MyBean
{
     myList = WebServices.getList();
}
```

In this scenario, the entire page starts to render only after the web service returns all data.

Where should I call the webservice (i.e., do `myList = WebServices.getList();` ) in order to have the rest of the page load in parallel, and show a progress bar or something in the datatable while the webservice runs?

I guess my concepts about the JSF/IceFaces lifecycle are not clear...

Also, this is not about lazy loading, because for that we would have to implement pagination in our datatabase query, too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around using Threads.

```
public class MyBean
{
    private ArrayList myList;
    private PersistentFacesState state;

    public MyBean
    {
        state = PersistentFacesState.getInstance();
        myList = new ArrayList();
        new Thread(new RunService()).start();
    }

    public class RunService implements Runnable
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                list = WebServices.getList();
                state.executeAndRender(); //Need to do this to update view

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Initally I was not aware of the `PersistentFacesState` and `executeAndRender();` , so even though the thread would update the array list, the view wasn't being refreshed. This was because the JSF/IceFaces lifecycle had already ended.

Persisting the view and then re-rendering it solved this problem, too.

Hope this solution helps someone.